# Abrir App en Android a partir de Link html en Excel

Tags: android, app

Intento conseguir que una app instalada en android pueda ser abierta desde un link en un libro de excel (drive spreadsheet offline) archivado en el teléfono..pero no lo consigo. Requiero de su ayuda por favor.. Son cerca de 2000 registros. Cada registro tiene un link en donde de manera concatenada llevará los valores para los campos del formulario que abrirá en la aplicación (jotform)..se espera que al abrir el formulario permita el ingreso (en la aplicacion) de información adicional (de cosecha) y se proceda al almacenamiento. Actualmente me envia a su pagina www.jotform.com pero no reconoce que esta instalada la respectiva App.. Requiero por favor me indiquen como debo construir el link para conseguirlo.. muchas gracias

[image: Listado de registros con link]

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Ana, considera revisar [ask] y realiza modificaciones a tu pregunta, agrega lo que has intentado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico.